# Loop image convertion to base64 based on how many images are uploaded in file upload

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I loop this image convertion to base64 based on how many images are uploaded in file upload?

This script I am using, I want it to be looped based on how many images that are selected in the file upload:

```
<input id="inp" type='file' multiple>
<p id="b64"></p>
<img id="img" height="150">
```

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);

    function readFile() {
            var FR = new FileReader();

            FR.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                document.getElementById("img").src = e.target.result;
                document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
            });

            FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

    }


</script>

Thank you!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var bs64Array = []; 
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
function readFile() {
  var FR = new FileReader();
  FR.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    var image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = e.target.result;
    document.getElementById("b64").appendChild(image);
    bs64Array.push(e.target.result)
   });
   FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
</script>
```